# Does EcmaScript have any rule where whitespace is important for the compiler during parsing

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Python uses whitespace to denote blocks:

```
for x in range(0, 50):
    print x
```

In JavaScript we use curly braces for that purpose:

```
for (x in range(0, 50)) { print(x) }
```

I'm wondering if whitespaces has any significance in EcmaScript when parsing a program and creating AST?

I've looked at the sources of TypeScript compiler and it seems to be ignoring whitespace when parsing the source code.

Comment: *Automatic semicolon insertion* is the only example I can think of that makes white space have any significance in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2846283/4879

Comment: @pawel, I've found the relevant part in the spec. Only line terminators are important. I've added my own answer.

Comment: Of course whitespace is significant: it separates tokens! Are you talking about newlines and indentation only?

Comment: @Bergi, I'm talking about spaces and tabs. What do you mean it separates tokens? When scanner identifies tokens it doesn't use whitespace for that

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com Of course [whitespaces are used](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-white-space). They're what allow you to distinguish `newObject` from `new Object`.

Comment: @Bergi, aha, you're right, thanks a lot for the hint! It's important for the productions that have recursive nature, like [identifiername](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-IdentifierName), correct?

Comment: I'd rather put it as "It's important for the productions that may not contain whitespaces". Whitespaces basically act as delimiters between them, as defined in the [most basic syntax definition](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-InputElementDiv).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bergi noted, the whitespace is important during lexical analysis which allows a scanner to know when a particular token ends. For example, this is what allow distinguishing `newObject` from `new Object`. It's important for the productions that may not contain whitespaces. For example, since space cannot be derived from [IdentifierPart](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-IdentifierPart) it marks the end of the [Identifier token](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#prod-grammar-notation-Identifier). Whitespace is also defined as a separate production for all goal symbols, starting with the simplest one `InputElementDiv`:

```
InputElementDiv::
    WhiteSpace
```

During syntactic analysis only the line-terminators are important for the automatic semicolon insertion process. The rest of the white space is not relevant. Here is the quote [from the spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/index.html#sec-notational-conventions):

> Moreover, line terminators, although not considered to be tokens, also
>   become part of the stream of input elements and guide the process of
>   automatic semicolon insertion (11.9). Simple white space and
>   single-line comments are discarded and do not appear in the stream of
>   input elements for the syntactic grammar.